# How do I use checkboxgroup input to come up with a datatable in R shiny?

Tags: r, checkbox, datatable, shiny, dt

- I am using datatable from DT package
- trying to use checkboxgroup input so that I can select multiple variables for table's output

I have researching no google to find some example codes but it was hard to apply.

Any experts can help!?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` to subset your data according to the checkbox input.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput('checkbox', 'select columns', names(mtcars), inline = TRUE),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
  ),
  function(input, output)
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ mtcars[input$checkbox] })
)
```

**EDIT**: Here is some code to illustrate what I mentioned in the comments

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput('checkbox', 'select columns', unique(mtcars$gear),
                       unique(mtcars$gear), inline = TRUE),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
  ),
  function(input, output)
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
      subset(mtcars, gear %in% input$checkbox) 
    })
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think I am getting close to where I want. This is coded for choosing what columns we want to show. Is there any way that we can do it within a column? like I want to show data table that gear == 4. So checkboxgroup will be Gear 1 to 5. I hope what I said makes sense.

Comment: Thank you 
Gregor de Cillia

    library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput('checkbox', 'select columns', unique(mtcars$gear), inline = TRUE),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
  ),
  function(input, output)
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ mtcars[mtcars$gear==input$checkbox,] })
)



I found this works how I want!

**Is there any way that the check boxes are all checked when we open the web?**

Comment: `checkboxGroupInput` has an argument `selected` which will define what choices are chosen initially. If you use the same value as in `choices`, everything should be selected